# count value in If statement for different condition's result

Tags: php

Each customers who buy 5 products, they will get bonus of 2 products.

However, each customer who buy 10 products, they will get bonus of 6 products.

The problem now is what if there is customer who buy 26 products?

So the condition will be :

the customer buy

```
 (10 x 2) //get 6 products x 2 = 12 products bonus/free 

   + 

 (5 x 1) // get 2 products x 1 = 2 products bonus/free
```

So far here is my condition:

```
if ($quatity > 4 && $quatity < 10){
    echo "Congrats, you get 2 products free"
}

if ($quatity > 9){
    echo "Congrats, you get 6 products free"
}
```

The code above is working fine with me if only the customer buy more than 5 or 10 products.

But as I mentioned above, what if the customer buy more than 10 products such as 26 products or 200 products? Should I write if function manually such as `if ($quatity > 9){}`,`if ($quatity > 19){}`, `if ($quatity > 29){}`, `if ($quatity > 39){}`, and so on,

OR

can anybody figure out the simple way for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the form for user? and add more part of your code when processing user action

Comment: Theoretically `if ($quatity > 4 && $quatity < 10)` this will only match if it was more than 4 and less than 10. It does not check whether it is equal to or less/greater than. So you would need to do `if ($quatity >= 4 && $quatity <= 10)` - This is a sidenote of course which will give you an insight as how to go about it.

Comment: @Fred-ii thanks for your beautiful sidenote. I will edit it. :)

Comment: You're welcome Alisa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will give you what you want.

It will break down the 10 products bonus, and then see if there are any 5 bonus left to give.

```
$tenBonus = (int)($quatity / 10);
$fiveBonus = $quatity % 10 > 4 ? 1 : 0;
$bonus = ($tenBonus * 5) + ($fiveBonus * 2);
if($bonus > 0) {
    echo "Congrats, you get ". $bonus ." products free";
}
```

Comment: But I need to make an if statement before echoing that. How to do this like: `if ($bonus) {echo "Congrats, you get ". $bonus ." products free";}` ?? Just to check if there is a bonus. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain it to me what this mean `$quatity % 10 > 4 ? 1 : 0` so that I can figure it out how you do that, please.. Many thanks.